# Do we need extensions for adding new functionality in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2.3, extensions

I can see in the Magento marketplace, there are so many third party extensions are available. My doubt is, if we want to implement the small functionalities like Scroll to top, banner slider, etc., 'do we need to use extensions because we can simply make them by adding some small scripts?' So what is the point of these extensions.

Also, I want to know do we really need modules to add functionality?

I want to add price slider in category page of my website. For achieving this, do i need to use module/extension?

Thanks for your time. Looking for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to use Magento third party extension. Magento by default provide all eCommerce functionality by default, only you will need to design them accordingly.

But if you want any custom functionality which is already not available in Magento then you can use any third party extension according to your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

It simply depends on your requirements. If you want to allow other users to manage the functionality from the backend, then the module/extension is necessary.

If you simply want to use Javascript slider, scroll to the top, etc. functionality and don't want to manage it by configuration or add flexibility to manage various options from the backend, you can do it without a module/extension.

One thing to be noted is even you don't create a module/install an extension, you need to follow Magento's standards to call a file.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. Do we create price slider without using extension? Please guide me.

Comment: I haven't used such functionality yet. For easy understanding, you can download a free extension for price slider, check their frontend code, and use this code as per your requirement.

Comment: You may need to set some values in JS code which the extension is getting from configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will try it